# Trouble with character column from a file read in with read.csv in r

Tags: r, read.csv

On the website:

http://naturalstattrick.com/teamtable.php?season=20172018&stype=2&sit=pp&score=all&rate=n&vs=all&loc=B&gpf=82&fd=2017-10-04&td=2018-04-07

the bottom of the page there is an option to download csv.  I downloaded the csv file and renamed it Team Season Totals - Natural Stat Trick 2007-2008 5 vs 5 (Counts).csv.  I also put the csv file in my directory.

I successfully read in the file using read.csv.

```
teams <- read.csv(file = "Team Season Totals - Natural Stat Trick 2007-2008 5 vs 5 (Counts).csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(teams)
  ï..                 Team GP      TOI  W  L OTL ROW   CF   CA   CF.   FF   FA   FF.   SF   SA   SF.  GF  GA   GF.  SCF  SCA  SCF. SCGF SCGA SCGF. SCSH.
1   1   AtlantaÂ Thrashers 82 3539.050 34 40   8  25 2638 3512 42.89 2002 2717 42.42 1505 2052 42.31 125 172 42.09 1195 1500 44.34   83  126 39.71  6.95
2   2 PittsburghÂ Penguins 82 3435.417 47 27   8  40 2820 3380 45.48 2192 2542 46.30 1580 1812 46.58 142 122 53.79 1343 1374 49.43  112   90 55.45  8.34
3   3   Los AngelesÂ Kings 82 3502.333 32 43   7  27 3008 3576 45.69 2306 2787 45.28 1649 1961 45.68 137 174 44.05 1049 1286 44.93   63   80 44.06  6.01
4   4  MontrealÂ Canadiens 82 3475.183 47 25  10  42 3089 3601 46.17 2266 2603 46.54 1617 1863 46.47 144 138 51.06 1156 1221 48.63   62   61 50.41  5.36
5   5     EdmontonÂ Oilers 82 3442.633 41 35   6  26 2958 3424 46.35 2255 2585 46.59 1601 1830 46.66 143 166 46.28 1334 1398 48.83  104  116 47.27  7.80
6   6 PhiladelphiaÂ Flyers 82 3374.800 42 29  11  39 2902 3343 46.47 2188 2505 46.62 1609 1857 46.42 125 137 47.71  919 1028 47.20   61   68 47.29  6.64
  SCSV. HDCF HDCA HDCF. HDGF HDGA HDGF. HDSH. HDSV.  SH.   SV.   PDO
1 91.60  388  468 45.33   51   82 38.35 13.14 82.48 8.31 91.62 0.999
2 93.45  503  444 53.12   79   49 61.72 15.71 88.96 8.99 93.27 1.023
3 93.78  270  356 43.13   29   36 44.62 10.74 89.89 8.31 91.13 0.994
4 95.00  271  322 45.70   25   31 44.64  9.23 90.37 8.91 92.59 1.015
5 91.70  443  452 49.50   57   61 48.31 12.87 86.50 8.93 90.93 0.999
6 93.39  257  266 49.14   24   24 50.00  9.34 90.98 7.77 92.62 1.004
```

The one thing I noticed was the Team Column had a accent in it:

```
teams$Team

[1] "AtlantaÂ Thrashers"     "PittsburghÂ Penguins"   "Los AngelesÂ Kings"     "MontrealÂ Canadiens"    "EdmontonÂ Oilers"       "PhiladelphiaÂ Flyers"  
 [7] "St LouisÂ Blues"        "ColoradoÂ Avalanche"    "VancouverÂ Canucks"     "MinnesotaÂ Wild"        "FloridaÂ Panthers"      "PhoenixÂ Coyotes"      
[13] "Tampa BayÂ Lightning"   "BuffaloÂ Sabres"        "ChicagoÂ Blackhawks"    "New YorkÂ Islanders"    "NashvilleÂ Predators"   "AnaheimÂ Ducks"        
[19] "BostonÂ Bruins"         "OttawaÂ Senators"       "DallasÂ Stars"          "TorontoÂ Maple Leafs"   "CarolinaÂ Hurricanes"   "ColumbusÂ Blue Jackets"
[25] "New JerseyÂ Devils"     "CalgaryÂ Flames"        "San JoseÂ Sharks"       "New YorkÂ Rangers"      "WashingtonÂ Capitals"   "DetroitÂ Red Wings"
```

Removing the accent:

```
teams$Team <- sub(pattern = "Â", replacement = "", teams$Team)
teams$Team[1]
[1] "Atlanta Thrashers"
```

Now when I want to subset the data based on Team, all the values come back FALSE:

```
teams$Team[1]
[1] "Atlanta Thrashers"
teams$Team[1] == "Atlanta Thrashers"
[1] FALSE

dplyr::filter(teams, Team == "Atlanta Thrashers")

 [1] ï..   Team  GP    TOI   W     L     OTL   ROW   CF    CA    CF.   FF    FA    FF.   SF    SA    SF.   GF    GA    GF.   SCF   SCA   SCF.  SCGF  SCGA 
[26] SCGF. SCSH. SCSV. HDCF  HDCA  HDCF. HDGF  HDGA  HDGF. HDSH. HDSV. SH.   SV.   PDO  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

It comes back FALSE for every team and I don't understand why?  Something with the accent that I removed?  Does it have to do something with encoding, i.e., utf-8?  If someone could please assist me I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to do with the accent.  I used:

```
iconv(teams$Team,, "UTF-8", "UTF-8",sub=' ')

iconv(teams$Team, "UTF-8", "UTF-8",sub=' ')[1] == "Atlanta Thrashers"

[1] TRUE
```

I never had that happen to me and have no experience with encoding and utf-8.